# I am getting error while installing packages in react . Please tell me what should I do?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm facing some error during the installation of packages in NPM in my ReactJS Project.

Node:- `16.17.0`.

NPM version:- `8.15.0`

React version:- `18.2.0`.

Here is my Error in image's form:- [Error PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipN3B.png).

Here is the Error which I'm facing now.

```
PS E:\react_projects\tic-tac-toe> npm i @material-ui/icons
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: tic-tac-toe@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR! react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0 || 17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm ERR!
node_modules/@material-ui/core
npm ERR!
from @material-ui/icons@4.11.3
peer @material-ui/core@"^4.0.0"
node_modules/@material-ui/icons
@material-ui/icons@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!
PS E:\react_projects\tic-tac-toe>
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-12-23T11_19_39_5177-debug-0.log
```

Can anyone resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

###### Hi @aakash,

As you can see in the above image. There is a `conflict` with the version of `React` And you want to install `@material-ui/icons` package. But, The things are, `@material-ui/icons` requires a version of **React** that is compatible with `@material-ui/icons` package. The version you are using now is `18.2.0`. So, you could just install `16.8.0` or `17.0.0`. For resolve that issue.

Here is an example. How you can be downgrading the version of React.

> `npm install react@^16.8.0` or `npm install react@^17.0.0`.

Alternatively, you could do that method. Which I not recommend. To update the version of `@material-ui/core` which is compatible with your `React` version.

For example:-

> `npm install @material-ui/core@^5.0.0`.

Also, The another option would be to use `--legacy-peer-deps` flag. It's useful when you are trying to install a package that has `peer dependencies` that are `not compatible` with the `current versions` of those dependencies.

> `npm install @material-ui/icons --legacy-peer-deps`

**Note**:- It may be a better solution to resolve the dependency conflict by `updating` or `downgrading` the versions of the packages involved, as I suggested earlier, rather than using the `--legacy-peer-deps` flag.

Answer (score 0):

install the package and use --force in last for example
npm i --force
eg
npm i @material-ui/icons --force

Comment: Instead of simply providing the answer directly, try writing a detailed comment that explains the solution, and also It's important to not just post code, but to also include a description of what the code does and why you are suggesting it. This helps others understand the context and purpose of the code, and makes it more useful for others who may be reading the question or answer . @NASIR ALI .

Answer (score 0):

as answered it is a version conflict but still, you can install any packages
just add --force to the end of every command.

before:

```
npm i @material-ui/icons
```

after:

```
npm i @material-ui/icons --force
```

Hope this solution help!

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to use the `--force` flag unless you are sure that you understand the potential consequences. For example, if the package you are installing has incompatible dependencies. It could cause errors or unexpected behavior when you try to run your application. But, it's useful if you want to override the dependency constraints specified in the package file. @Shashank.

Comment: yeah, correct agree with your answer! @DSDmark

Answer (score 0):

I guess you fetched node_modules a long time ago.

material-ui/core@ is deprecated , therefore you cant use that package for now.

best thing you can do tho, go to your package.json file and delete dependency lines with core@ and icons@, also delete your node_modules and ran npm install command in your terminal, after that,  you can also install icons@ package.

Comment: That will effectively reset your project's dependencies and allow you to install the latest versions of @material-ui/core, which may be compatible with the version of React you have installed. However, this approach may have unintended consequences. @goga iosebashvili.

Comment: can you elaborate?